# How find the largest square side length

Tags: geometry

If a square in the interior of the cube or boundaries, Find the largest square side length of $a$, if  the length of the cube as $1$
[image]

and this problem is from china
[image][image]

Comment: I think you'll find what you need at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/15498/problem-equivalent-to-largest-square-in-a-cube

Comment: Thank you,@GerryMyerson,I find sometimes, I can't find solution with the largest is $\dfrac{9}{8}$,can you help me,Thank you,and I think this is good problem

Comment: Maybe a better link is http://planetmath.org/geometry and scroll down to the discussion of "square in a cube". Someone called dh2718 gives an answer, then has more posts giving more details. Maybe you could study those and then post a summary as an answer here.